# Ordered sampling with replacement.

Tags: combinatorics

An elevator in a building starts with five passengers
and stops at seven floors. Assume that every passenger is equally
likely to get off at each floor and all the passengers leave
independently of each other.

Then the sample space is made of $7^5$ outcomes.

I wonder how $7^5$ is determined. Why not $5^7$ is true?

In general, I am really confused in the problems of determining numbers of arrangements with replacement. I am not sure what should be base and what the power. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base is the amount of different outcomes of an event.
The power is the amount of independent events measured.
I would step back to simpler examples: throw of a coin, roll of a die.

For a coin = $2^n$
if you flip the coin three times, the number of different set of outcomes is $2^3=8$
{HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT}
The same if you had three coins and flipped all together only once.

For a die = $6^n$.
It is the same if you throw the die twice or throw two dice at once, the different ways the pair might come is $6^2$.

In your case the outcome is which floor (7 possible outcomes), for each passenger to step out. How many ways 5 passengers might leave the elevator? $7^5$

Answer (score 1):

The number of outcomes is just the number of possibilities. To determine that you should first experiment with smaller numbers like 3 floors and 2 people, by listing all possible solutions, to get familiar with it. Don't try to figure out what must be the base and what must be the power. Simply try to understand how you should go about counting everything systematically without missing any, then the method and answer will follow naturally.